# ¿Por qué al añadir la propiedad display: inline-block a un label aumenta su margen?

Tags: css

Tengo un `<div>` que contiene un `<label>`, pues bien, al añadir la propiedad CSS `display: inline-block` al `<label>` aumenta el margen o el `padding` de éste (no sé por qué), aquí el ejemplo:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
  var label = document.getElementById("label");
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    label.style.display = 'inline-block';
    label.innerHTML += ', algo traviesa ;)';
  }, 2500);
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#cont {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #dedede;
}

#label {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <label id="label">Soy una etiqueta</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto se debe a que las etiquetas `label` son elementos `inline` por defecto, lo que significa que estos elementos no pueden tener altura ni anchura y se ajustan expresamente al contenido del elemento.

Ejemplo:

```css
#label{
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<label id="label">Esto es una prueba</label>
```

Si te fijas, tanto la anchura (`width`) como la altura (`height`) no se aplican a la etiqueta `label`.

La propiedad `padding` tiene un efecto un poco curioso con los elementos `inline`, ya que solo tiene en cuenta el lado izquierdo y derecho pero no el superior y el inferior a la hora de tener en cuenta el espacio con el resto de elementos.

Ejemplo:

```css
#label{
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<label id="label">Como puedes ver, el padding solo se aplica a izquierda y derecha</label><span>Si te fijas, el span solo respeta la parte posterior pero no la inferior del padding</span>
```

Como puedes observar en el ejemplo anterior, solo tiene en consideración el `padding` tanto a la izquierda como a la derecha de la etiqueta `label`, pero no encima o debajo de ella para posicionar el resto de elementos.

**Por lo tanto, ¿por qué cuando usamos la propiedad `inline-block` el `padding` aumenta?**

En realidad no aumenta, si no que al establecer un elemento como `inline-block` quiere decir que se comporta como un elemento `inline` (puede estar con otros elementos en la misma línea, se ajusta al contenido, etc...) pero a su vez tiene en cuenta las propiedades de los elementos `block` (tiene en consideración propiedades como la altura y anchura, `padding` en todos sus lados, etc...).

Es decir, el `padding` realmente no aumenta, si no que se aplica en todos sus lados y por eso da un efecto de que está aumentando cuando le añadimos la propiedad `inline-block`.

Veamos el ejemplo anterior pero usando `inline-block` en la etiqueta `label`:

```css
#label{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<label id="label">Como puedes ver, el padding solo se aplica a izquierda y derecha</label><span>Si te fijas, el span solo respeta la parte posterior pero no la inferior del padding</span>
```

Como puedes ver en este último ejemplo, el `padding` se aplica al elemento `label` y la etiqueta `span` respeta dicho `padding`.

Comment: @Javi Podrías agregarle la propiedad `inline-block` al label desde CSS sin tener que insertarselo por medio de Javascript. De esta manera, aplicaría el padding desde el principio y no se vería ese efecto extraño.

Comment: El problema es que estoy haciendo un plugin que tiene que hacerlo del modo que he mostrado, es decir, como la etiqueta label no permite meter dentro de ella ningún elemento dinámicamente a no ser que se establezca block, inline-block en ese label, por lo tanto no puedo hacerlas todas por defecto inline-block, ya que a lo mejor el usuario que use mi plugin no añade la propiedad **display: inline-block** en la etiqueta, me explico?

Comment: @Javi Realmente si le quieres añadir un `padding` inferior y superior a tu `label` solo lo podrás hacer mediante `block` o `inline-block`. En caso de que no sea necesario añadirles este `padding` superior e inferior entonces puedes usar las propiedades `padding-left` y `padding-right` para aplicarlo solamente a izquierda o derecha o, lo que es lo mismo: `padding: 0 20px`.

Comment: @Javi tu pregunta está de sobra respondida por Francisco, has preguntado porqué ocurre y ahí está la explicación. Ahora quieres otro comportamiento pero ya sería una pregunta distinta y habría que ver como se consigue porque es así como funcionan `inline` e `inline-block`.